# How to handle api server down

Tags: react

I build my website with react + redux and i read my datas from an API on an others server, so one server can be down and the others not.

Here is the condition of my question:

- The API server is down, the users can't get the datas
- The react server is up, the users can get the 'interface' but with no contents from the API.

I don't really now how to handle this:

- I just put a warning message in place of every containers that usually need some data from my api.
- I redirect them to a server down page ?

Any others idea would be great thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error messages should be informative and reassuring. Whether to choose for a full blocking solution or smaller error messages depends on the rest of the functionality on the page. Are you blocking the user from performing any other tasks they might be able to perform on the page?

You'll want to let them know they got on the page like they intended. If they see an other page entirely, they might think they did something wrong and try again. If you can't show the interface, you might be able to mimick it to some extend.

Be honest about what's wrong. Tell it in a matter they understand. Telling them the API is down probably says little to them.
Also, show them a way out. Tell them what they can do about it.
If they just have to wait, try back later, tell them you know and you're fixing it.

Comment: thanks for your advice, i know more what i'm going to do, just a simple and clear message 'thanks to try back later i'm working on it' in place of the content normally loaded.